# Why does canvas arc stroke ends distorted in Safari? (iPhone and M1 Mac)

Tags: html, iphone, canvas, safari, apple-m1

I am using the following code to draw a arc using html5 canvas.

This is my code. (Also have a CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/tzz1555/pen/VwrrJOP))

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.lineWidth = 40;
// ctx.lineCap = "square"

ctx.beginPath();
// ctx.arc(100, 100, 80, Math.PI*11/6, Math.PI*2/6);
ctx.arc(100, 100, 80, -Math.PI * 1 / 6, Math.PI * 2 / 6);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas> Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

If I run this code with Safari, the arc looks like this:
[Arc in safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrYNG.jpg)

But Chrome will give the expected result:
[Arc in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHLj4.jpg)

I have tried some different start angles and end angles, not all combinations of angles have this problem. In the example below, even adding 0.0001 to any angle could give the expected shape.

Could anyone please tell me why this occurs? Why is the arc different in Safari?

> Chrome: Version 98.0.4758.102
> Safari: Version 15.3 (17612.4.9.1.5)
> UA: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.3 Safari/605.1.15
>
> Chrome: Version 98.0.4758.102
> UA: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36

---

Edit:
I am using a M1 Macbook and I think this caused the problem. Like [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido)'s comment, I can't reproduce on any Intel-based MacBook. I also tested **different iPhones**, and they all give the distorted shape.

> iPhone: iPhone 11 Pro Max/iOS 15.1; iPhone 12 Pro/iOS 15.2.1; iPhone 12/iOS 15.3.1

Comment: That's a rounding error in their engine, not much you can do apart from [letting them know](https://bugs.webkit.org/). Note that I was personally unable to reproduce with the 17612.4.9.1.8 build, nor with the current Technology Preview (Safari 15.4, WebKit 17614.1.1.5). You may want to try disabling GPU acceleration ("Develop" menu, "Experimental Features"), but that wouldn't help your users who may face the same issue.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks! I can't find a menu with "GPU acceleration" but only have "GPU Process: Canvas Rendering" and disable it doesn't help.  I edited the question about some test on Intel Mac and iPhone Safaris. I guess there's something related with apple.